# How to run web components based HTML without node?

Tags: node.js, polymer, web-component

I was following the section "How do I use a web component?" from

[What are web components?](https://www.webcomponents.org/introduction)

end very soon I realized that node and npm it's a must. On top of that you have to run node to serve it.

Code

```html
<html>
<head>    
    <script type="module" src="node_modules/@polymer/paper-button/paper-button.js"></script>
</head>
<body>    
    <paper-button raised class="indigo">raised</paper-button>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the simplest - **no node** - way to run this simple web component?

Comment: you don't need node nor npm to use [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), the question should read *How to run package `@polymer/paper-button` without node?*

Answer (score 4):

Disregard everything "Polymer",
better yet... burn it down, throw your coffee over every monitor you see that title.

It was based on the **V0** implementation of Web Components;
which basically was Google's `lets-throw-something-at-the-wall-and-see-if-other-vendors-adopt-it` attempt at forcing Web Components on us.

That whole V0 era is what gave "Web Components" a bad reputation, and catchy blog titles like
"*The Broken Promise of Web Components*"
(but everyone involved learned what **not** to do)

Since years, all Browsers vendors work together on **V1**

Web Components run in all modern Browsers.. period.. so all you need is a Browser..
no built steps.. no bundlers.. no parcel.. no Svelte-compiler... no Rome... no fuss

Use any online editor like JSFiddle or CodePen, or your own IDE, or use your F12 Sources panel
and with a few lines of code you are started

```html
<my-component name="Alex"></my-component>
<script>
  customElements.define("my-component", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = `<h2>${this.getAttribute("name")} his very first Custom Element!</h2>`;
    }
  });
</script>
```

The 3 **distinct** (each can be used without the other) technologies making up "Web Components" help you built more complex Components

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM

Soon you will read about Lit and Hybrids and Stencil and uCe, and all types of tools that make developing Web Components "easier"...
They are just that... **tools**; You pick one or two **once you fully understand the technology**

Answer (score 2):

The *simplest* way would probably be to just include the script via a CDN like UNPKG https://unpkg.com/.

```html
<html>
<head>    
    <script
        type="module"
        src="https://unpkg.com/@polymer/paper-button@3.0.1/paper-button.js?module"></script>
</head>
<body>    
    <paper-button raised class="indigo">raised</paper-button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be nice to show the steps to achieve that without relying on CDNs